# C# last 3 working days of a month

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I need to figure out if the current date is one of the last 3 working days in a month

Is there a cleaner way of doing this instead of just having a bunch of conditional logic, e.g If today is workday > If add 3 days is weekend or next month

etc

Cheers

Comment: Is your work day definition exact same as the *week day*? Or do you care about local holidays, like national and religious days?

Comment: Hi Vahdet, we only really care about week days at the moment, cheers

Comment: Can you post what you already have?  Stack Overflow isn't a code request site - it's for getting help with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a method to determine the last 3 work days and check if the given date is part of it

```
public static List<DateTime> GetLastWorkingDays(DateTime date)
{
    List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
    date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    while(result.Count < 3)
    {
        // > 0 to exclude sunday, < 6 to exclude saturday
        if((int)date.DayOfWeek > 0 && (int)date.DayOfWeek < 6)
        {
            result.Add(date);
        }
        date = date.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`Contains()` to search within your result

```
bool valid = GetLastWorkingDays(date).Contains(date);
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, for anyone interested it turns out we did need to know if it was a bank holiday, and to not include this. To do this i have used fubo's code and added in a simple database command to make sure the date isn't in a list of bank holidays